# Potential bug or unexpected behavior in Property::isEmtpyValue

Tags: hiconic

If I have a GenericEntity E

```
entity E
 - property P
```

where P is any nullable type. Why is then:

```
E = E.T.create();

EntityType<GenericEntity> type = E.entityType();
for (Property p : type.getProperties()) {

  if (p.isEmptyValue(E))
    continue;
            
  // why does the code arrive here ??? 
  Object whyIsThisANullObject = p.get(E);
}
```

For an unititialized E, why is the `isEmptyValue` not `true` even if the `whyIsThisANullObject` will always be just a `null` object?

It this a bug or just strange behavior?